Ubuntu Studio 22.04: Problems Installing Pipewire
I followed a tutorial here to install Pipewire.
After completion I ran pactl info and the Server Name remained at PulseAudio and wasn't followed by (on Pipewire X.X.XX).
Next I again followed the tutorial above to revert back to PA.
Now when I run:
systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager
I receive the below and mod.rt isn't happy. Do I need to do something with the Studio low latency kernel?

Update: Second fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with default desktop, above had xubuntu-desktop added, same results. Fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04, no problems. Must be the Kernel being LL.
